# How to play short sounds while swiping pages on android

Tags: android, media-player, android-viewpager

I want to play a short sound file(e.g. mp3,wav).How to play short sounds while swiping pages.How can I change my code, I want to add mediaplayer.Please help me. (The sounds in the raw folder)

Thanks a lot,

```
package ro.ovidiuconeac.horizontalviewswiping; 
import ro.ovidiuconeac.horizontalviewswiping.R; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.Toast; 

public class CustomPageChangeListener implements OnPageChangeListener,OnClickListener { 

private Button buttonBlue   =   null; 
private Button buttonYellow =   null; 
private Button buttonRed    =   null; 
private Activity context    =   null; 

/** 
 * Constructor 
 */  

public CustomPageChangeListener(Activity context) { 
this.context = context; 

} 

public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

} 

public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

} 

public void onPageSelected(int position) { 

switch (position) { 
case 0 : { 
    buttonBlue = (Button)    context.findViewById(R.id.buttonBlue); 
    buttonBlue.setOnClickListener(this); 

    break; 
    } 
    case 1 : { 
    buttonYellow = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.buttonYellow); 
    buttonYellow.setOnClickListener(this); 
    break; 
} 
case 2 : { 
    buttonRed = (Button) context.findViewById(R.id.buttonRed); 
    buttonRed.setOnClickListener(this); 
    break; 
} 
}    
} 

public void onClick(View v) { 

// Click button blue 
if (buttonBlue != null && v.getId() == buttonBlue.getId()) { 
Toast.makeText(context, "Blue screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

} 

// Click button yellow 
if (buttonYellow != null && v.getId() == buttonYellow.getId()) { 
 //  Toast.makeText(context, "Yellow screen",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 

// Click button red 
if (buttonRed != null && v.getId() == buttonRed.getId()) { 
Toast.makeText(context, "Red screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

}    
} 

}
```

Comment: use sound pool for that  instead of mediacontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should put pagescroll.mp3 file in assets folder , then you can use following code :

```
public static void pageScrollSound(Context context) {
private static MediaPlayer player;
private static AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor;
    try {
        assetFileDescriptor = context.getResources().getAssets().openFd("pagescroll.mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.LOG_TAG, "IOException", e);
    }
    try {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.LOG_TAG, "IllegalArgumentException", e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.LOG_TAG, "IllegalStateException", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.LOG_TAG, "IOException", e);
    }
}
```